# Tracing SegWit transaction via blockchain.info

Tags: transactions, blockchain.info

Blockchain.info give some strange information. For example for transaction `6e58d8c695e3e42c5a7807e2ed99ad7f7731658dfb0d62cdfef44dad8964b350`.

Outputs is in unreadable format. Please can you help to find out why outputs in such unreadable encoding?

The basic question is how to find next transaction by the one of the outputs?

Comment: no, this is not a duplicate, and at the same time not a segwit, see description below. The interesting part in this tx is however, that output goes to bc1 addresses... There the output scripts are different from standard scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Tracing SegWit transaction via blockchain.info

This is not a segwit transaction, this tx starts with:
    01000000048583473E2F1AE32B7C4397D85B041DA5BC75C7CCD3CE9EAD9374EDB27FEE888100000000FC...

and translates to:

```
VERSION
 01000000
TX_IN COUNT: hex=04, decimal=4
 TX_IN[0]
  TX_IN[0] OutPoint hash  8188EE7FB2ED7493AD9ECED3CCC775BCA51D045BD897437C2BE31A2F3E478385
  TX_IN[0] OutPoint index hex=00000000, decimal=0
  TX_IN[0] Script Length  hex=FC, decimal=252
  TX_IN[0] Script Sig     ... <sig>
```

whereas a segwit tx would look like this (marker and flag):

```
VERSION     01000000
SEGWIT (BIP141): this is a segwit tx, marker=00
       (BIP141): flag=01
TX_IN COUNT: hex=04, decimal=4
```

As the sigs are part of the Input section of the tx, one can derive easily, that it is no segwit.

The tx has 4 multisig input parts, and 58 output parts. The output is mostly structured like this:

```
 TX_OUT[56]
  TX_OUT[56] Value (uint64_t)
  hex=F06B011B00000000, reversed_hex=000000001B016BF0, dec=453078000, bitcoin=4.53078000
  TX_OUT[56] PK_Script Length (var_int)
  hex=22, dec=34
  TX_OUT[56] pk_script (uchar[])
  002014B288DCA5D59CAA8868D1668C97C971E58AB3CCF10534AC567EA51AA8ABA299
    20: OP_Data32
```

--> This is an UNKNOWN script, but represents a BIP173 representation of a segwit address.

Two observations:
the amount of 58 outputs is certainly not a standard tx, and the many amounts of bitcoins, which are shifted around enorm. Looks to me like an exchange, which is shifting data between live accounts and cold storage... The script is indeed not a standard script (OP_DUP, OP_HASH, ...). The spending tx needs to meet this output data, and I am not quite clear how this condition can be met. So I think OPs question can be rephrased: "how to redeem a tx with a bc1 type segwit address". Maybe some experts here have a better inside view?

Comment: here is no experts?

Comment: Reviewing bticoin wiki, and the BIPs (141,143,173): "a native P2WSH scripPubKey of 34 bytes. It starts with a OP_0, followed by a canonical push of the scripthash (i.e. 0x0020{32-byte keyhash})" - so it represents the hash of a script that currently only the owner knows (until it is spent on the blockchain). Similiar to P2SH addresses.